# Recursive function for pair of numbers

Tags: php, function, recursion

I want to create a recursive function that displays in order n numbers from greatest to 2 that are  pair. If `n=5` it should display:

> 10 8 6 4 2

To get the pair number displayed, I am using:

```
if($i %2==0)
echo $i
```

to order from the greatest I also use `i--`. The problem is I don't know how this recursive function really works.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This community does not exist to do your homework. We expect people to ask questions that show what you've tried and where you suspect you're running into problems.

Comment: You should write some code.

Comment: nothing at all i know how to write this code with for loops but the exercise demand to use recursive function and i dont understand it very well. any help is appreciated

Comment: the function should be function pair($n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this...

```
<?php
$inc=2; 
recv(7); // Calling your recursive function i.e. passing the parameter 5 or 7

function recv($v) // Your function definition
{
global $inc;
if($v>=1)
{
echo $inc*$v." ";
$v--;
recv($v); // Function calls itself in other words "recursive call"
}
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
14 12 10 8 6 4 2
```